# Java: How to Create an instance of a subclass from with a Static method of the super class

Tags: java

My specific problem is that I want to create a static method in a base class which saves away the instances of the subclass in a file. And another static method in the base class which retrieves the data and recreates the instances of the subclass.

I have got all of it working except where in my strategy I need to create an instance of the subclass within the static method of the base class. Please see what I mean below.

And so the general question is in Java how do you Create an instance of a subclass from within a Static method of the superclass.

```
class Base

    public static Void saveAllInstances(){
       saveAttributesofAllInstancesInFile();  // this works
    }

    public static Void retrieveAllInstances(){
       destroyAllInstances(); // this works
       getInstanceAttributesFromFile();  // this works and returns e.g. ArrayList<HashMap>

       for( instanceAttributes : retrievedInstances ){

         // Here is the part I cant figure out: I want to create an instance of 
         // the subclass here 
         sub = new Sub();

         sub.setAttributes(instanceAttributes); //this works
       }
}

class Sub extends Base{
}
```

Comment: The answer is don't. Never have dependencies from parent classes to their child classes.

Comment: I suggest you read on the Factory pattern (and its variations, like the Abstract Factory and Factory Method), and see if this can help you improve your code.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the factory pattern, check out this link to learn more about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java_2.

Comment: So how do I solve my specific problem. It would seem the code to save and retrieve all instances is mostly common across all the subclasses.  So you can see why I want it in the super. Are you saying I have replicate in each subclass I create?

Comment: Factory looks promising thanks.

Comment: How do you know which subclass to create?

Comment: Describe what you are trying to accomplish (not how you are trying to do this by having a class save all created objects of itself and extended class objects).

Comment: Generally speaking it is considered bad practice to have your a class have responsibility for persistence, and something else (Seperation of Concerns). It is even worse using Polymorphism for this. Typically you would use a DAO pattern for retrieving and even persisting various objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the factory pattern works fine. And looks something like this in pseudocode:

```
class MainFactory{

    protected Worker makeWorker(){
        return new Worker();
    }

    public createIntanceOfSubworker(){
       Worker i = makeWorker()
    }
}

class SubFactory extends MainFactory{
    @override
    protected SubWorker makeWorker(){
        return new SubWorker();
    }
}

class Worker{
}

class SubWorker extends Worker{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that your code isn't valid Java syntax, exactly the way you've done. However as others have suggested what you're doing is actually probably better suited for a (Pure Fabrication) Factory Pattern.

Base.java

```
public class Base {
    public static void retrieveAllInstances() {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
    }
}
```

Sub.java

```
public class Sub extends Base{
}
```

Works fine. Apart from the cyclic reference, but if you don't care about maintainability, knock yourself out.

Comment: But Base doesnt have a clue about the subs that will be implemented in the future. What I really want is self instance = new self where self refers to whatever sublcass this static retrieveAllInstances is operating in. I am  trying to figure out how to form a Factory Pattern to do all this but I keep getting wrapped around the axle wanting to be able to override a static method which seems not to be allowed.

Comment: If anyone would like to show even a pseudo code example of how to implement this using a Factory pattern I would be happy to accept it. I am still not quite grocking it.